Distribution of the number of passing trains
We stand at the station and count the passing trains. The first train arrives at a random time having an $Exp(\lambda)$ distribution, $\lambda > 0$. And each following train comes after the previous one through an independent random time with an $Exp(\lambda)$ distribution. The random variable $X_{T}$ is equal to the number of trains that have passed by time T. For a given $T > 0$ find the distribution of $X_{T}$.
I have a solution, but it seems too abstract to me. I'd like to know if a more explicit answer can be found and if I made any mistakes.
description of my solution:
We need to find distributive function $F(k) = P(X_{T} < k), k \in N$
$k = 0: F(0) = P(X_{T} \le 0) = 1 - P(X_{T} > 0) = 1 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_{T} = n) $
$k = 1: F(1) = P(X_{T} \le 1) = P(X_{T} = 0) + P(X_{T} = 1) = 1 - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 
P(X_{T} = n) $
...
$k = s: F(s) = 1 - \sum_{n=s+1}^{\infty} P(X_{T} = n) $
Use convolution: $P(X_{T} = 1) =  \int_{0}^{T}{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}  dx} = 1 - e^{-\lambda T}$
$P(X_{T} = 2) =  \int_{0}^{T}{P(X_{T} = 1) P(X_{T-t} = 1) , dt}$
...
$P(X_{T} = s) =  \int_{0}^{T}{P(X_{T} = s-1) P(X_{T-t} = 1)  dt}.$
(I did not express $P$ explicitly because it has a complex form and does not seem to simplify with large s.)
And are all these equalities correct?

Do you know about a Poisson process? https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_1_2_basic_concepts_of_the_poisson_process.php

The number of independent events with the same rate in a fixed time span is regulated by the Poisson Distribution. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution. See the Related distribution section, with a derivation.
